# how to install curl for health check of spring boot jib docker image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, aws-fargate, jib, health-check

You define jib image in pom file, but I need curl command-line to be running on the container to do health check on aws ecs. How can I add curl into that image?

Comment: Which docker base-image you are using? and can you add `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: @nischaygoyal I do not know which image, but that comes thru:
<groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>

Comment: it's an interesting question, but I wonder why do you need curl at all inside the image? can't you just define Liveness, Readiness probes end expose then accordingly?

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci The spring boot app exposes /actuator path in url to monitor health check of the app which can only be accomplished with a 'curl' command that can run inside a ECS fargate container deployment. How can health check be added in ECS fargate is the first problem. Also the app has got several tasks running in parallel, so if any of them fails, the whole container needs to be killed and a new instance of container needs to be booted up. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Use EKS as you then get many things for free, like helthcheck and automatic healing. in that case is kubernetes that checks the health of your pod and creates a new one in case of a not healthy pod, then the idea of many parallel tasks in a container does not sound a good practise... You get overall a much beter devops experience...

Comment: I have used both EKS and custom managed k8s cluster too, to keep things simple, we are running containers as fargate tasks and it is very simple, no fancy stuffs. The problem here I am talking about is not related to container deployment technology whether ECS, EKS or Custom managed k8s. The liveness and readiness probe also can't tell you if the internal task of the container app has failed, the health checks are based on listening http status on a port but not sure for newer versions of k8s above from 1.15. In my case, the container needs to be killed if internal task has failed ...

Comment: ... parsing the task status from HTTP 200 response json. You get HTTP 200 response even if the internal task might have failed. I know I won't get the answer but just giving you more context for you to broaden yourself as it is not always a pet store app that you can switch to run on ECS today, EKS tomorrow and Azure cloud next day. Also, the container I am talking about is based on vendor managed Red Hat UBI image, so we have no control how they bundled parallel tasks as a customer service inside this, we are only interested in this service and we can only change few configurations ...

Comment: ... on how to communicate with our other micro services.

Comment: thanks @ArmandoBallaci hope this discussion also gives an insight on how new microservices and legacy systems are being engineered and at the same time how they co-exist together to provide a business value and sleek customer experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jib is distroless, so curl can't be installed on jib images. It can easily be installed if I want to go with one of the distro based images.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may put `curl` using Jib's `<extraDirectories>` feature, which enables adding arbitrary files to the target image. Check the [Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) and [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) docs for more details. As explained in the docs, you will also need to configure `<permissions>` to set executable bits to `curl`.

If you prefer, you could even set up your Maven or Gradle builds to download `curl` and unpack it. Here's an [example Jib setup](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/examples/java-agent) (showing both Maven and Gradle) from the Jib repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own Docker image with all the necessary tools in it. For example, you can use `ibmjava:8-jre-alpine`,
and for how to use it in jib, just run the goal with below specified parameter of that custom image.

```
mvn compile jib:build \
    -Djib.from.image=ibmjava:8-jre-alpine
```

You can write your own Dockerfile to create any custom image in which you install all the cli-tools if it's not present in that base image. and then push it to container registry and then use it as mentioned-above.

Comment: The above maven jib plugin was producing a very small java app bundled image with ZERO vulnerabilities as scanned by AWS ECR scanner as attached in the picture. I can create my own docker file and add those I know, but I didn't find those images clean against vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you try a custom image and see

Comment: There are a lot of custom images, I tried openjdk and open jre alpine images, but still they have minimum of 2 high vulnerabilities

Comment: any suggestion of an image that has a small footprint like max 100 MB and vulnerability scan passed ?

Comment: For any small images, it's always `alpine` based and try installing cli tools whichever you want.

Comment: https://ibb.co/6DLbkBt
Please have a look of maven-jib created application image, vulnerability = None and footprint ~ 97 MB

Comment: Everything is good, I just need to install curl and jq on that image which I can use for AWS fargate health check. But how to do in jib thingy is my trouble.

Comment: Better try with `alpine` base and install whatever is necessary if you want customization

Comment: Have a look at this github issue:- https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/676

Comment: Thats a very generic answer, yea most would know the pros and cons of alpine. If someone asks me in general, I would answer the same way but I am looking for a specific answer here to create a Dockerfile that meets the criteria of less than 100 MB app image size, vulnerability check passed and allows to install cli packages on top of that.

Comment: Good that I found an alpine image that satisfies my requirement: ibmjava:8-jre-alpine

Comment: That's great. Have added to the answer. you can accept and close it